# Скачать данные из Parse.com в массив

Tags: java, android, массивы

Пытаюсь скачать данные из таблицы Parse.com в массив, имею следующий код:

```
 public static void update_Parse(){

    final List<String>[] list11 = new List[]{new ArrayList<String>()};
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> pQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Friendlist");
    pQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                if (list.size() > 0) {
                    ParseObject p = list.get(0);
                    if (p.getList("reFri") != null) {
                        list11[0] = p.getList("reFri");
                    } else {
                        list11[0] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "TAGLIST" + list11);
        }
    });
}
```

Как понять, скачиваются ли эти данные вообще?

В логе отображается каждый раз новый набор цифр и букв, смысл которого мне не очень понятен:

```
TAGLIST[Ljava.util.List;@42aba1e0
```

UPD: ` public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

```
private int[] image_resources = {R.drawable.fr1, R.drawable.fr2, R.drawable.fr3, (остальной список из 20 картинок)  };
private static int[] image_friend_null = {R.drawable.fr_null, R.drawable.fr_null, R.drawable.fr_null, (остальной список из 20 картинок) };
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
static final String TAG = "myLogs";
private static int PagerNumber;



public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

public CustomSwipeAdapter() {
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image_resources.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
    return (view == (LinearLayout) o);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    TextView textView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_count);
    ImageView imageViewShowPresent = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.friend_null);


    imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
    textView.setText("iMAGE: " + position);


    imageViewShowPresent.setImageResource(image_friend_null[position]);
    PagerNumber = position;
    Log.d(TAG, "position: " + PagerNumber);
    container.addView(item_view);
    return item_view;
}

public static int get_position() {
    Log.d(TAG, "PROVERKA");
    return PagerNumber;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: " + position);
}

public static void change_img_friend(){


    image_friend_null[2] = R.drawable.fr_null;
    ... 
}`
```

Предпоследний вариант, предложенный @s_klepcha , работает более-менее, но возвращает null в логах. А хотелось бы, чтобы возвращал значение в столбце таблицы Parse (в данном случае 1 или 0). 
Вот этот вариант:

```
public static void Parse_go_to_refresh(){


    final List<List<String>> list1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> pQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Friendlist");
    pQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (list.size() >= 0) {
                for (ParseObject po : list) {
                    List<String> result = po.getList("reFri");
                    Log.i(TAG, "TAGLIST - " + result);
                    Log.i(TAG, "TAGLIST2- " + list);
                    list1.add(result);
                }
            }
        }
    });




}
```

Какой функции я добиваюсь: 
я делаю резерв из списка, который листается. Из Parse я пытаюсь достать информацию о резервах (1 или 0 в значении каждой строки в столбце "ReFri").

Comment: новая ерунда - это hashCode() объекта, который по умолчанию есть адрес ссылки. Он всегда будет разным

Comment: С логом все правильно, в данном случае у коллекции List вызывается toString() по умолчанию, который и возвращает Вам адрес ссылки.

Comment: Log.i(TAG, "TAGLIST" + list1[0].toString());

Comment: ну да всё правильно! как бы не так, он вызывает toString для массива, а не для ArrayList-a

Comment: вот только NPE можно отхватить

Comment: @s_klepcha, вылетает NPE на ЛОГЕ. Что может быть не так?

Comment: упс, эт сморозил )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, кому-то понадобится. Подсказали на англоязычном stackoverflow:

```
   public static void Parse_go_to_refresh(){ 

   final List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
   ParseQuery<ParseObject> pQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Table");
   pQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
   public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
   if (list.size() >= 0) {

     for (ParseObject po : list) {
     // Get object id like this
     Log.i(TAG, "Id number " + po.getObjectId());

     list1.add(po.getObjectId());
     // Get number like this
     Log.i(TAG, "Id number (2) - " + po.getInt("id"));

     }}}});}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вобщем как то так:

```
         public static void update_Parse(){
           final List<List<String>> list1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
           ParseQuery<ParseObject> pQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Friendlist");
           pQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

              public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                if (list.size() > 0) {
                   for (ParseObject po : list) {
                     Set<String> keys = po.keySet();
                     for (key : keys) {
                        List<String> result = po.getList(key);
                        Log.i(TAG, "TAGLIST - " + result);
                        list1.add(result);
                     }
                   }
                }
              }
          });
        }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29346/discussion-on-answer-by-s-klepcha----parse-com--).